# How to avoid duplicate record while inserting data using user defined table type in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-insert, user-defined-types, check-constraints

I am trying to insert entire model in database using my .net application. I am using a user-defined table type.

This is my procedure and user-defined table; I am using SQL Server 2012.

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[TmpAccessRequest] AS TABLE
(
    [RequestId] [int] NULL,
    [RequesterID] [int] NULL,
    [RequestType] [int] NULL,
    [NextApprover] [int] NULL,
    [RequestStatus] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Delegation] [int] NULL,
    [CreatedOn] [date] NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [IsSepecialRequest] [bit] NULL,
    [DelegationDetailID] [int] NULL,
    [IsActive] [bit] NULL,
    [IsDeleted] [bit] NULL,
    [ModifiedOn] [date] NULL
)
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_SaveAccessRequest] 
   (@TmpAR TmpAccessRequest READONLY,
    @IsUAMSRequest BIT,
    @RequestID INT OUTPUT) 
AS  
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tblRequests (RequesterID, RequestType, NextApprover, RequestStatus,
                             Delegation, CreatedOn, CreatedBy, Description,
                             IsSepecialRequest, DelegationDetailID, IsActive, IsDeleted, ModifiedOn)
        SELECT
            RequesterID, RequestType, NextApprover, RequestStatus,
            Delegation, CreatedOn, CreatedBy, Description,
            IsSepecialRequest, DelegationDetailID, IsActive, IsDeleted, ModifiedOn
        FROM
            @TmpAR  

    SET @RequestID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    --SET @RequestID=IDENT_CURRENT('tblRequests') 
    SELECT @RequestID
END
```

I want to check if duplicate data should not insert at the same time. So how can I do that with user-defined table type ?

Comment: Which columns are to be considered not get duplicate data here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the changes done to your script to avoid inserting duplicate record. So i considered two columns data should be unique to avoid  duplication for user understanding purpose

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_SaveAccessRequest] 
(
  @TmpAR TmpAccessRequest READONLY,
  @IsUAMSRequest bit,
  @RequestID int OUTPUT
) 
AS  
BEGIN

     Insert into tblRequests
    (
       RequesterID
      ,RequestType
      ,NextApprover
      ,RequestStatus
      ,Delegation
      ,CreatedOn
      ,CreatedBy
      ,[Description]
      ,IsSepecialRequest
      ,DelegationDetailID
      ,IsActive
      ,IsDeleted
      ,ModifiedOn
    )
    SELECT
       RequesterID
      ,RequestType
      ,NextApprover
      ,RequestStatus
      ,Delegation
      ,CreatedOn
      ,CreatedBy
      ,Description
      ,IsSepecialRequest
      ,DelegationDetailID
      ,IsActive
      ,IsDeleted
      ,ModifiedOn
     FROM @TmpAR  
     WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 
                        FROM tblRequests i
                        INNER JOIN @TmpAR o  
                            ON i.RequesterID = o.RequesterID
                         AND i.RequestType = o.RequestType 
                         AND i.NextApprover = o.NextApprover)

     SELECT @RequestID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

     SELECT @RequestID
END
```

Comment: That prevents you inserting a duplicate of an existing row. It doesn't prevent you from inserting two (or more) new rows in one go that are duplicates

Comment: What do you mean Two or more rows in one go @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: The original version of this answer prevented you from inserting a row (in `@TmpAR`) that was a duplicate of a row already in `tblReqeusts`. It didn't prevent you from calling the stored procedure with two duplicate rows in `@TmpAR` itself. Sreenu131 has made changes to their answer since but I've not yet worked out whether the changes cover both cases.